# Can't able to review Flagged Posts in Low Quality Posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug

I found this [POST](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/38153) under Low Quality Posts. But I couldn't able to review the post .

When I click on Recommended Close button I got a popup like the following. but there are no radio buttons to select one of the reason.

[image]

I think the reason for that is, I already flagged that question for closure.(Ofcourse, not from Low Quality Posts wizard)

If so why did I get this question under Low Quality Post (When I visit [Review](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review) page I get 1 Low Quality Post)

Is it a bug? or it's by design? If it's by design what should be done in this case?

I faced the same case for *First Posts* and *Late Answers* couple of times, but there I get a pre-enabled button "*I'm done*" but for there is no such feature for  *Low Quality Posts*